# Need a help to setup a color scheme of Rubymine 4.5 in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, rubymine

I saw some articles describing how to change the default color scheme of Rubymine. But they did it either in Mac OS or in Windows. I want to make the color scheme of my Rubymine 4.5 in Ubuntu exactly like TextMate has at railscast.com.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Color scheme configuration doesn't depend on the platform, the steps are the same on Linux, Mac and Windows. Go to `Settings` (`Preferences` on Mac) | `Editor` | **Colors & Fonts** and select one of the predefined schemes:

[image: schemes]

As you can see, **RailsCasts** scheme is already bundled. You can also use [Color Scheme Tool](https://github.com/JetBrains/colorSchemeTool) to convert other TextMate schemes to RubyMine. XML file with the scheme should be placed in the `config/colors` directory when IDE is not running. `config` directory location [would depend on the OS](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-181). For RubyMine 4.5 on Linux it would be `~/.RubyMine40/config`.

Comment: Yes, I saw it. The font is different. I think it's Monaco_Linux. I installed it, however Rubymine doesn't see it. Your thoughts?

Comment: Only Java supported Unicode fonts are displayed. If copying the font file under jre/fonts doesn't work, you will have to find another compatible font.